# Cordova features aren't work on server

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am a developer of DisciplineXgames! We are developing a mobile app. We have downloaded the Cordova test suite from here (https://github.com/apache/cordova-mobile-spec). When I upload this on DisciplineXgames server it shows an error in alert box "Error: Apache Cordova did not initialize.  Demo will not run correctly." but when we upload the same folder on Phonegap server it works perfectly fine. Unfortunately this doesn't solve our problem as we are building our mobile app on our server and just using Phonegap to redirect the user to the page hosted on DisciplineXgames server if there's Internet in the user's mobile.

First error which I got in the console area in Google Chrome is cordova.js missing when I provided that than it outputs another error that is cordova/channel is required.

Hope you can guide us through how we can use Cordova's amazing features on our server instead of Phonegap's local server.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused as to what you are trying to accomplish here but I am going to take a stab.

You want to develop an app that when the app launches, it checks to see if the device has internet connectivity. If it does, then the app just opens the mobile website hosted on your servers. if there is no internet connectivity then the app ???

Since this is a very simple use case for an app, I would avoid using cordova and instead use [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/apps). Simply write an index.html page and a .js file to check for the connectivity and then use the inappbrowser plugin to open your mobile site if there is connectivity. Once that is done, zip your package, upload to phonegap build and then download your compiled apps.

phoneGap Build allows you to avoid the app building overhead and the need to install things BUT prevents you from taking advantage of some of the deeper configurations and some plugins. But again, for your simple use case, PhoneGap Build sounds like the way to go.